# Wordpress Website not updating with changes to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a website and I have created a Wordpress plugin for a search bar. The plugin has a js folder and file but the changes made to that file are not appearing on the website.

I have cleared my browser's data, my server's cache (Cloudways Varnish), and have installed a plugin to clear Wordpress cache (Cloudways' Breeze). None seem to work.

I can see on the Wordpress Plugin file editor that the JS file is updating, but the changes are not appearing on the live website.

dynamic-search-plugin.php file:

```
<?php

function enqueue_ajax_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-search-ajax', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/dynamic-search.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'dynamic-search-ajax', 'dynamicSearchAjax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( 'dynamic-search-nonce' )
    ) );

}

function dynamic_search_handler() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'dynamic-search-nonce', 'nonce' );

    // Retrieve the search query from the AJAX request
    $query = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['query'] );

    $results = array(
        array( 'name' => 'Test 1' ),
        array( 'name' => 'Test 2' )
    );

    // Return the search results as a JSON response
    wp_send_json( $results );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dynamic_search', 'dynamic_search_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dynamic_search', 'dynamic_search_handler' );
```

The dynamic-search.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    // Event handler for search form submission
    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log("On submit in JS called");
        e.preventDefault();

        var query = $('#search-input').val();

        // Make AJAX request to the server
        $.ajax({ //only this is run for some reason
            url: dynamicSearchAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'dynamic_search',
                nonce: dynamicSearchAjax.nonce,
                query: query
            },
            success: function(response) {
                displayResults(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });

    // Function to display search results
    function displayResults(results) {
        var container = $('#results');
        container.empty();

        // Loop through the results and create buttons
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            var button = $('<button>').text("Test"); //changing this code doesn't correspond to changes on website
            container.append(button);

            // Add click event handler to the button
            button.on('click', function() {
                // Perform an action when the button is clicked
                alert('Button clicked:'); 
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens in worpdress sometimes when it caches your script, Try adding `time()` param to your script file like below,

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-search-ajax', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/dynamic-search.js?time='.time(), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

Comment: Please don't post answers as comments, and if you also post an answer you should go clean up your comments.